# Convert encoding before inserting into a database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, encoding

I'm working on a program that reads data from a flat file and inserts it into a database on a sql server. The problem is that the file is encoded with codepage 850 while the database is using codepage 1252. That means I have to convert the encoding of the string I'd like to insert.

I use this method for the conversion:

```cs
        private Encoding _sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
        private Encoding _destinationEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

        private string AdjustCodePage(string msg)
        {
            byte[] source = _sourceEncoding.GetBytes(msg);
            //byte[] destination = Encoding.Convert(_sourceEncoding, _destinationEncoding, source);
            return _destinationEncoding.GetString(source);
        }
```

But this method doesn't give me the expected result. When I select the data from the database, all special characters like 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' are replaced with an '?'

Why does my conversion not work?

Comment: A `string` is always UTF-16. The conversion you're applying here doesn't make any sense - if you make sure you read the strings from your flat file using the correct encoding, then the string should have the correct data in it, and you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: `string` is always Unicode, you have to do the decoding/encoding on the edges of your system, i.e. apply the decoding when reading the string from the file and let ADO.NET (or whatever you use for database access) hande the database encoding.

Comment: Thanks  @JonSkeet that helped me. It's working now!

Comment: @Tomsen SQL Server has no encoding issues if you save text in `nvarchar` columns either. You really have to do *nothing* to include Chinese, German and Cyrillic text in a single field. StackOverflow is proof of this - a .NET application saving text in `nvarchar` fields. That's why I can write `Αυτό εδώ` and  `ä`,`ö`,`ü` and expect the comment to appear without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet and Klaus Gütter stated in their comments, a string is always UTF-16. That means, that `AdjustCodePage` <s>doesn't do anything, because the string itself stays the same.</s>  does not work like I wanted to.

To get the expected result I had to change the way I'm reading the file. So I switched from

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

to

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath, Encoding.GetEncoding(850));
```

That way the conversion takes place at the edge of the system, just before the actual string is created.

Credits going to Jon Skeet & Klaus Gütter!

Comment: "That means, that AdjustCodePage doesn't do anything, because the string itself stays the same" - no, AdjustCodePage definitely *does* do something... it loses information! It encodes a string with one encoding and then decodes it as if it had been encoded as a different encoding (like trying to interpret a PNG file as if it were a JPEG).

Comment: Why save a file with this codepage to begin with? The StreamWriter and StreamReader classes in .NET Core and .NET Old (at least in recent versions) use UTF8 by default.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know... I didn't make this file.